# CSS indent line to the last line

Tags: css, newline, space, indentation

How can I add such an indentation in CSS?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to do what you're asking in pure CSS. The only solution I can think of is adding a span around the part you want pushed down, then setting the relative height to whatever your `line-height` is (in this case, `1em`).

```
span {
 position: relative;
 top: 1em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ptZkc/1/

You **will** see an issue when the span starts a new line as exhibited in the jsfiddle above

Comment: Hey! My only problem with your idea, if I have more paragraph, then all of them will moved together, no space / gap is between them.

Comment: Add padding to the bottom of the `p` tag.

Comment: @Switz, If you want multiple blocks to be connected this way, you have to nest the spans. I don't think it is possible using just css to lay out sibling (non-nested) blocks the way you want it.

Comment: Yes, they are/have to be nested. See the jsfiddle.